# Mulitple Docker Compose: fetch fails with error 'getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN'

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, next.js, docker-for-windows

I have a project, where frontend and backend are separated. I've managed to connect those apps via `docker network`. But now I'm stuck with error from frontend app

`FetchError: request to http://nginx:80/Api/Pages/GetHeaderMenuElements/ failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN nginx`

`docker-compose.yml` for frontend:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  next:
    container_name: ${APP_NAME:?err}-next
    #restart: 'always'
    #ports:
    #  - "41000:4000"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: tail -F anything

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: 'custom-net'
```

`docker-compose.yml` for backend:

```
version: '3'
services:
  #some services were removed
  php:
    restart: always
    links:
      - mariadb
      - memcache
      - mailer
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/php.Dockerfile
    container_name: ${APP_NAME:?err}-php
    volumes:
      - './etc/php/php.ini-production:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini'
      - './www/:/var/www/html'

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: ${APP_NAME:?err}-nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '11000:80'
      - '44443:443'
    links:
      - 'php'
    volumes:
      - './www:/var/www/html'
      - './config/nginx/fastcgi.conf:/etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf'
      - './config/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf'
      - './config/nginx/snippets/:/etc/nginx/snippets/'
      - './config/nginx/conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/'   


networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: 'custom-net'
```

I'm able to reach `nginx` from `next` container via wget.

So my question is: how can I connect to `nginx`?

I'm using docker for windows

Comment: When you say "frontend app", is that an application running in a browser?  The browser isn't inside Docker (even if the Javascript files it runs are served from a container) and can't see the Docker-internal hostnames.

Comment: @DavidMaze yes, it is NextJs application. This error occurs while NextJs performs page generation